# Warning: ftp_rename(): User logged in (rename files with foreach loop)

Tags: php

I have a text file with bunch of file's path in my ftp server, I wanna rename all of them with foreach loop but PHP warns "User Logged in" and unable to rename them:

```
$links = file('filepath.txt');

foreach($links as $link){
    // connect and login to FTP server
    $ftp_server = "myftpserver";
    $ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
    $login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

    $old_file = $link;
    $new_file = str_replace("badword", "goodword",$old_file);

    // try to rename $old_file to $new_file
    if (ftp_rename($ftp_conn, $old_file, $new_file))
      {
      echo "Renamed $old_file to $new_file";
      echo '<hr>';
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Problem renaming $old_file to $new_file";
      }

    // close connection
    ftp_close($ftp_conn);
}
```

> Warning: ftp_rename(): User logged in

Comment: Why do you connect and login for every loop item? You should put that out of the loop. Are you in the correct directory (maybe lack of use of `ftp_chdir`)? Does the user have correct access rights in that path (file permissions)?

Comment: What happens if you open the connection and log in outside the foreach loop (then close after the loop too)?

Comment: @MarkusZeller, @FelippeDuarte, I took ```$ftp_server```,```$ftp_conn```,```$login``` outside of the loop but still cannot rename them PHP: ```ftp_close(): supplied resource is not a valid FTP Buffer resource``` and also i'm sure i have a premission to rename files becuase it works when i try to rename the single file

Comment: ftp_close should be outside too

Comment: Not working ```ftp_rename(): supplied resource is not a valid FTP Buffer resource``` again

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, If i try to rename multiple path, the items should be in array and i dont why, when i try to use `file` method it not working somehow...

it works:

```
$links = [

    '/path/file.pdf',
    '/path2/file2.pdf',

];
```

It not working if i put them in plain text file:

path.txt:

/path/file.pdf

/path2/file2.pdf

```
$links = file('path.txt');
```